# rotating the grid to plot horizontal errors bars with Hmisc::xYplot in R

Tags: r, lattice

I'm using xYplot to plot my regressions results with error bars. However, xYplot only plots horizontal error bars, and I need vertical error bars. Looking around for a solution, I found [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Hmisc-or-Lattice-plot-with-error-bars-Depth-independent-variable-on-Y-axis-td811365.html) where someone asked roughly the same question. After some messages, the user who asked the question says that "I just  discovered that using the xYplot (Hmisc) and rotating the grid
viewport (and the labels etc) given me exactly what I need".

So I looked around on how to rotate the grid and found that using grid library and pushviewport etc. you can rotate the grid. However, my code isn't working. Here is what I tryed so far:

```
estimate=structure(list(coefi = c(-5.08608456607495, -4.17906898422091, 
-2.85696514398422, -3.06968196245069, -2.73660002514793, -1.0017403629931, 
-1.66291850690335, 0.431265159072978, -0.472895611533531, 0.845421348865878, 
-0.437434919008876, 0.269041451577909, -0.233066564595661, 0.0137190330621302, 
-2.94808159763314, 1.9166875739645), lower = c(-8.1895, -6.8485, 
-5.214125, -5.532875, -5.106625, -3.271625, -3.97375, -0.09773, 
-1.340625, 0.415125, -0.86615, 0.02665125, -0.5861, -2.079, -5.626625, 
0.8115125), upper = c(-2.11475, -1.611125, -0.5602375, -0.7309625, 
-0.3721375, 1.259875, 0.7167875, 0.9672875, 0.39035, 1.30025, 
-0.05634125, 0.5115, 0.07237875, 2.14275, -0.3653, 4.202625), 
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
16)), .Names = c("coefi", "lower", "upper", "x"), row.names = c("alpha.1.", 
"alpha.2.", "alpha.3.", "alpha.4.", "alpha.5.", "alpha.6.", "alpha.7.", 
"b.income", "b.democracy", "b.ginete", "b.educ", "b.patent", 
"b.fdi", "b.0", "mu.alpha", "sigma.alpha"), class = "data.frame")

legenda=c(as.character(seq(1970,2000,5)),"PIB_pc", "democ",  "legis", "educ", "patent", "FDI",  "b.0", "mu.ano", "var.ano" )

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(angle = 90, name = "VP"))
upViewport() 
xYplot(Cbind(coefi,lower, upper) ~x, data=estimate, , varwidth = TRUE, ylab="Betas",
xlab="Inclinação das Covariáveis com respectivos 95% intervalos de credibilidade \n N=409",
ylim=with(estimate,c(min(lower)-.5, max(upper)+.5)),  scales=list(cex=1.2, x = list(at=seq(1,16,     by=1), labels = legenda)) ,abline=c(list(h=0), lty="dotted", col= "grey69"), xlab.top="Adesão ao Tratado de Cooperação de Patentes, 1970-2000", draw.in = "VP")
```

I'd apreciate any help.

Update: there were comments pointing that the code was right. So I'm wondering if I'm not being able to communicate what I want or if it's a bug... So I'll post an imagem of the output of my code right now and you tell me if the code in you computer is giving the same output or another one:

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more specific with what help you need?  I ran your code, and this produces a chart with horizontal error bars.  What else is wrong?

Comment: Really? in my computer it produced vertical error bars, i.e, the the bars vary in the y axis, not in the x axis. And I need to have variables in the y axis and bars varying in the x axis...

Comment: @Andrie - Maybe this is an R version or platform issue, as when I run his code I get vertical error bars as well. (R 2.13.0 OS X)

Comment: I updated the post and inserted my output. I'm mad and when I say horizontal you guys understand vertical and vice-versa, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to directly call `print` on lattice object (it's mentioned in grid documentation `RShowDoc("grid", package="grid")` - "Adding lattice to grid"):

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(angle = 90, name = "VP"))

print(
    xYplot(Cbind(coefi,lower, upper)~x, data=estimate, , varwidth = TRUE,
        ylab="Betas", xlab="Inclinaçao das Covariáveis com respectivos 95% intervalos de credibilidade \n N=409",
        ylim=with(estimate,c(min(lower)-.5, max(upper)+.5)),
        scales=list(cex=1.2, x = list(at=seq(1,16,by=1), labels = legenda)),
        abline=c(list(h=0), lty="dotted", col= "grey69"),
        xlab.top="Adesao ao Tratado de Cooperaçao de Patentes, 1970-2000",
        draw.in = "VP"
    ),
    newpage=FALSE
)
```

[image: Rotated xYplot]

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how do I rotate the labels etc. as well?

Comment: @Manoel I think you must struggle with `scales` and other basic lattice options (I have no idea how to move title, but I'm not lattice guru).