# Vertical box-percentile plot with Lattice & panel.bpplot

Tags: r, panel, lattice

I am drawing box-percentile plots in R, using the box-percentile panel function from `Hmisc` (`panel.bpplot`) with `bwplot` from `lattice`.

I have a numeric vector (`Length`), and would like to show its distribution across the levels of a factor variable (`Month`).

Here's an example with fake data:

For example,

```
set.seed(13)
Length<-sample(1:10, 1000, replace=TRUE)
Month<-sample(c("Apr","May","Jul","Aug","Sep","Nov"), 1000, replace=TRUE)

df<-cbind(Month, Length)
df<-as.data.frame(df)   
df$Month<-factor(df$Month, levels=c("Apr","May","Jul","Aug","Sep","Nov"))
df$Length<-as.numeric(df$Length)

#plot horizontal box-percentile plot; 
bwplot(Month~Length, data=df, panel=panel.bpplot)
```

This works fine. But I want the plots to be *vertical*, with `Month` on the x-axis and `Length` on the y-axis. The documentation for `panel.bpplot` says that horizontal plots make category levels more visible, but, for my purposes, I specifically need a vertical plot. Is there a way to modify `panel.bpplot` to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the argument `horizontal`? See `bwplot` docs. Values can either be `NULL`, `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: I did try fiddling with the horizontal argument. Setting it to FALSE causes bwplot to treat my numeric variable as a factor, and my factor variable as numeric, which is not the desired effect (although it does create vertical boxes). Also, this is only the case when the regular panel function is called in bwplot. When panel=panel.bpplot, setting horizontal=FALSE appears to have no effect on the plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took some tips from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392266/rotating-the-grid-to-plot-horizontal-errors-bars-with-hmiscxyplot-in-r) and then merged it with your code. It seems the "trick" is setting up a rotated grid:

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(angle = 90, name = "VP"))
print(
    bwplot(Month~Length, data=df, panel=panel.bpplot, draw.in = "VP"
    ),
    newpage=FALSE
)
```

which results in:

[image]